# Csharp error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu

I've got the following warning on ubuntu 14.04 while compiling c#: warning CS8001: SDK path could not be resolved Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)

Though it will still execute using mono hellowold.exe. 
I'm just starting to learn csharp so please understand me.

I have installed csharp using this tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnhKj8c5TcE

Comment: The warning your given can be shown in many cases. It is however most likely that it is the `System.Drawing.dll`. Under windows this library would be installed with .net. In mono its not default, check if you have the `libmono-winforms2.0-cil` package installed.

Comment: how can i check that on ubuntu?

Comment: First you can search for the package (or the package that includes it) using `apt-cache search libmono-winforms2.0`. Once you find a package that includes it you can do `apt-get install PackageName`. It will give you a notification if its already installed.

Comment: Ok i have installed it and now it works fine. thanks a lot. that was really quick

Comment: Good to hear! wrote the answer below your question for future reference and others with the same problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved in the comments below the original question. this answer is a short summary for those who run into the same problem:

The missing SDK error can be given for many reasons, most of the times however its the **System.Drawing.dll** missing. This library is installed by default in .net but not in Mono. In Mono you will have to install the **libmono-winforms2.0-cil** package. Package can be installed using the package manager of your Linux distribution.

Comment: yup. useful for beginners like me. thanks to everyone