# CS8001: SDK path could not be resolved after compiling C# app on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

After searching around the web, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617920/csharp-error-on-ubuntu-14-04)  ask Ubuntu question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617920/csharp-error-on-ubuntu-14-04) Stack Overflow question, I'm having no luck in figuring out why I'm getting this warning after compiling a simple C# command line app via terminal. I'm using mono, and after

```
dmcs myProgramName.cs
```

I get

```
warning CS8001: SDK path could not be resolved
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
```

I read that Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 depends on libmono-winforms2.0-cil, but after trying to install that with

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-winforms2.0-cil
```

I get

```
Package libmono-winforms2.0-cil is not available, 
but is referred to by another package
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted,
or is only available from another source
However, the following packages replace it:
mono-reference-assemblies-2.0 mono-devel
```

Through more searching, I read that libmono-system windows-forms4.0-cil is what I need for Ubuntu 16.04, but after trying to install it I get

```
libmono-system-windoes-forms4.0-cil is already the newest version
```

Does anyone have any suggesstions on how to trace this compilation warning? I've reached a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Install the full mono-runtime and the full mono-development packages, then give compiling a try.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime

sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

If your goal is to have the least number of packages installed take a look at the mono [linker](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/#linker) to help you identify the minimum needed assemblies then locate the packages they belong to.

Comment: I can't update after that. I get "E: Type 'Executing:' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read." What did I break?!

Comment: Ok, I realized those first two commands were supposed to be separate lines. Removing the file in sources.list.d and starting over fixed it. However, after installing libmono-winforms2.0-cil, I get The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmono-winforms2.0-cil : Depends: libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libmono-system-web2.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. I also get the same warning after compiling.

Comment: Hmm, that is a strange one. Have you tried installing the full Mono-package and Mono-development package? Then I believe there is a way to find the minimum required packages for your app.  

`sudo apt-get install mono-runtime `

`sudo apt-get install mono-devel`

Comment: If that does work and you still desire the smallest mono foot print you can leave. Take a look at the [mono linker](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/#linker)

Comment: Installing mono-runtime and mono-devel did the trick! 
I tried to compile again with:
dmcs myProgramName.cs and got Note: dmcs is deprecated, please use mcs instead! 

So, after mcs myProgramName.cs it compiled with no warnings. :) 

If you'd like, turn that comment into an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks for your help.